# Integrating Users between my PHP site and WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, single-sign-on

We have a website that is written from ground up using PHP/Laravel and has its signup and sign-in process. We also added a hosted WordPress site, that used a WordPress plugin allowing users to sign up and sign-in.
Now, We are looking for a solution to have a single sign-in option that provides signup and sign-in for our entire site?

We would like to use the PHP/Laravel auth mechanism to provide authentication for the WordPress section?

Comment: Have you looked at using Laravel Passport? It's an oauth2 service, you may be able to leverage it.

Comment: Thank you @AndyHolmes. Will check it out.